# What is the correct semantics for language switching navigation?

Tags: html, semantic-web, semantic-markup, nav, microdata

I am coding a multilingual site and I have following navigation:

```
 <nav id="language">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/en/" hreflang="en">en</a></li>
      <li><a href="/de/" hreflang="de">de</a></li>
      <li>fr</li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

**Can I improve semantics?** With Microdata or tags attributes e.g

Comment: I'd use links with `<kbd>`'s. As for microdata, try searching for something suitable on [schema.org](http://schema.org/Language)

Comment: I wouldn't use <nav> at all as the links contained within are not really "major navigation" but would be suited more for the <menu> element which alas is not fully supported.

Comment: @OneTrickPony: Why on earth would you use `kbd` here?

Comment: @IanDevlin: Note that this note on "major navigation" is only a *note*. I think it's totally fine (and useful!) to use `nav` here. It matches the definition "a section of a page that links to other pages or to parts within the page" and I'd consider it also major, as this is the primary/only way to navigate to translations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### `abbr` elements

You should add `abbr`, giving the full language name in the corresponding language:

```
<nav id="language">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/en/" hreflang="en"><abbr lang="en" title="English">en</abbr></a></li>
    <li><a href="/de/" hreflang="de"><abbr lang="de" title="Deutsch">de</abbr></a></li>
    <li><abbr lang="fr" title="Français">fr</abbr></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

#### `title` attribute for `a`

You could add a `title` attribute to `a` with a content like: "Switch to the English translation of this page"

#### heading for `nav`

You could give this `nav` section a heading like "Translations of this page" (for the English page).

If you don't want it to be visible on the page, hide it visually so that it is still read to screenreader users (e.g. with the `clip` method).

(If you provide such a heading, you probably don't need the `title` attribute on `a` anymore.)

#### additionally: `link` element (in `head`)

For bots, you could link the translations with `link` elements in the `head` of your pages:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="/de/" hreflang="de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="/en/" hreflang="en" />
```

Comment: Note that instead of putting a link element, you can simply submit a sitemap. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps changing `en` to `Change site language to English` would improve semantics. As it stands `en` is pretty cryptic without the context.

Answer (score 2):

you should add a `lang` and `hreflang` attribute on the link, with an [IETF language tag](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47) (bcp47) as the target value, see e.g. the links in wikipedia's article on *water* to the same item in other languages:

```
<a lang="de" hreflang="de" title="Wasser" href="//de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasser">Deutsch</a>
```

NB: the `lang` attribute is not link specific. it specifies the language of the content of the tag (wikipedia puts it also in the `<html>`- tag and on the `<h1>` header-tag.), while `hreflang` specifies the language of the page you are linking to.